# Cross platform DateTimeOffset conversion to CST Time Zone

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, timezone

I've written the following code to convert the DateTimeOffset to CST DateTime

```
var bookingDateInCst = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(itemRequest.BookingDate, "Central Standard Time");
```

This works on my local machine, but when I deployed it on PCF cloud environment I get the following error
"The time zone ID 'Central Standard Time' was not found on the local computer."

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've used TZConvert utility, by reading this block

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/cross-platform-time-zones-with-net-core/

It helped me fix the issue using following code:

```
var cstTimeZoneInfo = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Central Standard Time");
var bookingDateInCst =TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(itemRequest.BookingDate.UtcDateTime, cstTimeZoneInfo);
```